# Is there a way to append data to google sheets while specifying the header?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In google sheets, I have a timeseries data that has many columns

| date | mcdonalds | kfc | anw | tacobell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-08-01 | 432 | 65 | 543 | 543 |
| 2017-08-02 | 76 | 53 | 74 | 32 |
| 2017-08-03 | 76 | 234 | 45 | 78 |

Every now and then, a new row is generated via python and is appended to google sheets.

This is my code snippet, the list variable is called *new_list*

```
new_list = pd.Series.tolist(df)

request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=gsheetid, range=sheet_name, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={'values': new_list})
response = request.execute()
```

However in my python code, sometimes, the column order may not be the same as my google sheets and in some cases there may be even new columns that are not yet present in google sheets

| date | kfc | burgerking | anw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-08-07 | 52 | 52 | 32 |
| 2017-08-08 | 726 | 45 | 53 |

Is there a way to append data to google sheets while specifying the header?

Comment: About `I have timeseries data that has many columns`, in this case, this table is a sample Spreadsheet? And, in order to correctly understand `However in my python code, sometimes, the column order may not be the same as my google sheets and in some cases there may be even new columns that are not yet present in google sheets`, can you provide your sample value of `new_list`?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that is a sample spreadsheet, and for your second question, I have updated  it with the resulting dataframe, I loop through it to get the list

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed the scripts of 2 patterns in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, your code is perfect! I have been using sample script 2 for a couple of days now and its been working correctly

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Spreadsheet as shown in the 1st table of your question.
- You have a dataframe as shown in the 2nd table of your question.
- You want to put append the values of dataframe to the Spreadsheet by checking the header row.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been getting and putting values to the Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, the values of dataframe are put into the Spreadsheet using the existing header row in your Spreadsheet. The header row of the Spreadsheet is retrieved by "Method: spreadsheets.values.update".

```py
# This sample value is from your question.
df = pd.DataFrame([["2017-08-07", 52, 52, 32], ["2017-08-08", 726, 45, 53]], columns=["date", "kfc", "burgerking", "anw"])

gsheetid = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet1" # Please set sheet name.
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds) # Please use your script here.

header = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=gsheetid, range=sheet_name).execute())["values"][0]
new_list = []
dic = df.to_dict("records")
for o in dic:
    temp = []
    for h in header:
        temp.append(o[h] if h in o else "")
    new_list.append(temp)
res = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=gsheetid,range=sheet_name,valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",body={"values": new_list}).execute()
```

- When this script is run to your sample Spreadsheet, the values of `new_list` of `[['2017-08-07', '', 52, 32, ''], ['2017-08-08', '', 726, 53, '']]` are appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the values of dataframe are put into the Spreadsheet using the existing header row in your Spreadsheet. The header row of the Spreadsheet is retrieved by "Method: spreadsheets.values.get". And, the header row is updated by "Method: spreadsheets.values.update".

```py
# This sample value is from your question.
df = pd.DataFrame([["2017-08-07", 52, 52, 32], ["2017-08-08", 726, 45, 53]], columns=["date", "kfc", "burgerking", "anw"])

gsheetid = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet1" # Please set sheet name.
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds) # Please use your script here.

header = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=gsheetid, range=sheet_name).execute()["values"][0]
dic = df.to_dict("records")
add_header = [k for k in dic[0].keys() if k not in header]
header = [*header, *add_header]
new_list = []
for o in dic:
    temp = []
    for h in header:
        temp.append(o[h] if h in o else "")
    new_list.append(temp)
if add_header != []:
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=gsheetid,range=sheet_name,valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",body={"values": [header]}).execute()
res = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=gsheetid,range=sheet_name,valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",body={"values": new_list}).execute()
```

- When this script is run to your sample Spreadsheet, the header row is updated by a new header row of `['date', 'mcdonalds', 'kfc', 'anw', 'tacobell', 'burgerking']`. And, the values of `new_list` of `[['2017-08-07', '', 52, 32, '', 52], ['2017-08-08', '', 726, 53, '', 45]]` are appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)